# How to repeat an ongoing script if the same input is given in autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

i use this code to send more mouse wheel scrolls using one notch, the problem is when an input is sent again before the loop is finished, it is not taken in account and the loop needs to end before relaunching

I tried looking for a way to break up the code if there is an input and relaunch it with no success

```
WheelUp::
loop 100
{
sendInput {WheelUp}
sleep 2
}
return
```

Expected behavior: on the 50th loop, if input is given again, reset the loop count (stop and relaunch the script) so the total repetitions would be 150

Comment: Does it work if you reformat the code to be a bit shorter?  `WheelUp::Send, {WheelUp 100}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach.
You have to change the [#MaxThreadsPerHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_MaxThreadsPerHotkey.htm) setting.

> This setting is used to control how many "instances" of a given hotkey
>   or hotstring subroutine are allowed to exist simultaneously. For
>   example, if a hotkey has a max of 1 and it is pressed again while its
>   subroutine is already running, the press will be ignored.

That will allow the hotkey to "interupt" itself.
Each time you scroll up while the hotkey is already active it will add another 100 scrolls to the loop.

```
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2
WheelUp::

if (counter > 0)  ; this means the hotkey is already active
{
    counter := counter + 100  ; in that case we just add another 100 scrolls to the loop
    return
}
else ; this means the hotkey is not active, we start fresh with 100 scrolls
{   
    counter := 100
}   

while, counter > 0
{
    sendinput, {WheelUp}
    sleep 40  ; change this to your requirement
    counter--
    ; tooltip, % counter   ; un-comment this line for testing

}

return

~WheelDown::counter := 0 ; extra hotkey to stop the loop immediately if needed
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and sorry for the late reply, indeed this solves the problem perfectly, i just made a second version of this counting from negative numbers to zero in case the mouse was scrolled in the other direction and added the condition of a lateral mouse button being pressed ( the overall goal being to get infinite scroll on a regular mouse)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot respond to the other comment but `WheelUp::Send, {WheelUp 100}` won't break the current 100 Wheelups and will add another 100 WheelUps. So if the input was given again on the 50th WheelUp, it would still send 200 WheelUps.

In the loop you will need a conditional statement to detect if a physical scroll up was detected recently, and then restart the loop if it does. For most keys you would use `GetKeyState` as the check in the if statement, however the mouse wheel has no state to detect.

In my example code, the Enter button will restart the loop. I'm not sure how to restart the loop if trying to use WheelUp again since there is no state to detect, and `A_TimeSincePriorHotkey` is not reliable because the loop is sending WheelUps.

```
WheelUp::
loop 100
{
    sendInput {WheelUp}
    sleep 2
    if (GetKeyState("Enter", "P"))
       Goto WheelUp
}
return
```

Comment: Indeed WheelUp::Send, {WheelUp 100} would technically solve the problem but the input is instantaneous so in this case the smooth scrolling is lost and becomes "jumpy",  For the other problem of the scroll wheel not having a state a trick i used in python was to set a variable to false before the loop and add another hotkey to change it to true, then use its state instead of GetKeyState, it basically changes to true and restarts the loop then gets reset when the loop is replayed